# Parallel programming with SWD pinouts

Tags: integrated-circuit, programming, flash, swd

I need to program 8 boards with SWD interface device but I have one programmer with 4 channels.

Is it sufficient if I connect SWD lines in parallel permanently to all 8 boards and just toggle the power in groups? First four powered on, then program. Switch off first '4 group' and power on the 2nd '4 group(5-8)' and program 2nd group?
Do I need to keep the RESET low for 2nd group when 1st is being programmed or power on/off is enough?

Comment: What kind of boards? What programmer?

Comment: the question is about SWD. The PCB board with nRF52 for example. Programmer with SWD - Algocraft.

Comment: Holding a device in reset will _probably_ cause it to keep SWDIO as an input. There will be additional loading, so you might need to lower the clock frequency.

Comment: @Lukasz How are you going to handle the output of each SWD? Connecting digital outputs is a bad idea and could result in destruction of the output driver. This question probably needs a diagram showing what you intend to do.

Comment: @Lukasz you probably need a multiplexer to communicate with each board in turn, or else you need to go through every detail of the SWD spec as customized to the MCU in question and also the electrical spec and verify no conflict with your plans. Consider one fast programmer or else four cheap ones run at the same time distinguished by the USB ports to which they are connected, or hanging off four raspberry pi's, or... just buy or contract the use of a **production** programmer instead of trying to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it sufficient if I connect SWD lines in parallel permanently to all 8 boards and just toggle the power in groups?

No. The unpowered chips will either not allow the SWD lines to go high or pull power of them if the driver is "strong" enough. Rememer that those I/O pins usually have diodes to both VCC and GND rails included.

Comment: So You answered "yes" to my question. I want to power 4 boards and program them, then power another 4 boards and program. When board is not powered then no matter what happens on SWD lines willl have no effect or side efeetcs?

Comment: NO NO NO. The unpowered boards - especially NRF52 - will conflict with the powered ones due to the voltage on the SWD lines providing power to *all* chips.

Comment: OK. then what can I do? Is grounding the RESET enough?